# Cannot resolve symbol 'MODE_PRIVATE'

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to open a database in Android Studio using the line:

`SQLiteDatabase gardenDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("myDatabase",MODE_PRIVATE,null);`

but it gives me the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'MODE_PRIVATE'`. I don't understand what is wrong as have used the exact same line of code elsewhere in my project in different classes and it has worked fine before.

My full code:

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

    public MyWorker (@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
    }

    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        SQLiteDatabase myDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("myDatabase",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        //Do stuff

        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

Imports:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import androidx.work.Result;
import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;

import static android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase;
```

I have been using this site to help write my database code: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Comment: Do you also have the import statements from those classes where this worked?

Comment: You probably want "Context.MODE_PRIVATE".

That said, SQLiteDatabase. openOrCreateDatabase() doesn't even take a "mode" as a second param. You may have it confused with another method or class.

Comment: @BarryFruitman this `openOrCreateDatabase()` is a method of the `ContextWrapper`class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the comments under your question, @BarryFruitman pointed out that:

> SQLiteDatabase. openOrCreateDatabase() doesn't even take a "mode" as a
>   second param

and after that I commented:

> this openOrCreateDatabase() is a method of the ContextWrapper class

and we are both right.
The problem is revealed now after you posted the link of the tutorial you follow. 
Indeed in this tutorial, this method is proposed:

```
SQLiteDatabase myDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("myDatabase",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

and this belongs to `ContextWrapper` class, 
**but** in the same tutorial the mentioned signatures of `openOrCreateDatabase()` are:

```
openOrCreateDatabase(String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)
```

and

```
openOrCreateDatabase(File file, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)
```

which are both members of the `SQLiteDatabase` class. 
I believe that this is the tutorial's mistake.
So change to this:

```
SQLiteDatabase gardenDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseNameWithPath, null);
```

which uses the method from `SQLiteDatabase` class.
**Edit**
Of course you have to provide for the variable `databaseNameWithPath` a fully qualified path and database name, like:

```
String databaseNameWithPath = "/data/data/" + <yourpackagename> + "/databases/" + "myDatabase";
```

and create the directory if it does not already exist.

Comment: Doing that gives me an error in my Logcat `Error Code : 1294 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT) Caused By: Specified directory or database file does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't imported that constant:

```
import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
```

Comment: When I add that it gives me the error `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'int', required: 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory'`

Comment: `import static android.content.Context` is enough.

Comment: @forpas not if you want to use the unqualified constant as OP has - for that you need to code the import as I have.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes he can use it unqualified by just: `import static android.content.Context`. Try it like I did.

Comment: @forpas In java, coding the unqualified enum constant name `MODE_PRIVATE` with `import static android.content.Context;` generates a compile error. You may only code the import either as `import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;` or `import static android.content.Context.*;`. As for android studio, I couldn't say because I don't have that installed to try.

Comment: @Bohemian I have it unqualified `int x = MODE_PRIVATE;` with only `import android.content.Context;` and there is no compile error.